# Having issues with compiling basic calculator

Tags: c, loops

I am new to programming and I was trying to build a basic calculator from my code below and it always exits from the loop before even entering.

don't know where I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int a,b,result;
   char oprtr;
   
   printf("Enter the first number\n");
   scanf("%d",&a);
   
   printf("Enter the second number\n");
   scanf("%d",&b);
   
   printf("Enter what do you want to do\n");
   scanf("%c", &oprtr);

   if(oprtr=='+')
   
   {
       result=a+b;
       printf("Addition = %d + %d = %d\n",a,b,result);
   } 
   else if(oprtr=='-')
   {
       result=a-b;
       printf("Subtraction = %d - %d = %d\n",a,b,result);
   }
   else if(oprtr=='*')
   {
       result=a*b;
       printf("Multiplication = %d - %d = %d\n",a,b,result);
   }
   else if(oprtr=='/')
   
   {
       result=a/b;
       printf("Division = %d / %d = %d",a,b,result);
   }

  
   
    return 0;
}
```

The output always exits before entering the loop.

```
Enter the first number
5
Enter the second number
2
Enter what do you want to do


...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no loop.  The problem is that %c reads the newline left over from the 2nd number.  To ignore leading white spaces, prefix the format string with space.  You make it harder for yourself by not checking return codes for functions that may fail.  Also fixed the `printf()` typo `-` in the `*` by reducing duplication (DRY).  I used a `switch` to show you a different approach but the if-else-if is fine, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;
    printf("Enter the first number\n");
    if(scanf("%d",&a) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int b;
    printf("Enter the second number\n");
    if(scanf("%d",&b) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char oprtr;
    printf("Enter what do you want to do\n");
    if(scanf(" %c", &oprtr) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *name;
    int result;
    switch(oprtr) {
    case '+':
        name="Addition";
        result=a+b;
        break;
    case '-':
        name="Subtraction";
        result=a-b;
        break;
    case '*':
        name="Multiplication";
        result=a*b;
        break;
    case '/':
        name="Division";
        result=a/b;
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid operator\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s: %d %c %d = %d\n", name, a, oprtr, b, result);
}
```

The next step, if you want to be fancy, is to realize that (symbol, name and the calculation) belong together.  This implies a `struct` and the corresponding variable `operators`.  I used a macro to generate the two different prompt functions.  Both implement error handling / retry.  You could use a macro to generate the operator functions but they are so small that it's easier just to write them out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PROMPT(type, format) \
    int prompt_ ## type(const char *prompt) {\
        for(;;) {\
            printf("%s\n", prompt);\
            type v;\
            if(scanf(format, &v) != 1) {\
                printf("scanf failed\n");\
                while(getchar() != '\n');\
                continue;\
            }\
            return v;\
        }\
    }
PROMPT(int, "%d");
PROMPT(char, " %c");

int addition(int a, int b) { return a+b; }
int division(int a, int b) { return a/b; }
int multiplication(int a, int b) { return a*b; }
int subtraction(int a, int b) { return a-b; }

int main(void) {
    int a = prompt_int("Enter first number");
    int b = prompt_int("Enter second number");
    char symbol;
    int op; 
    struct {
        char *symbol;
        char **name;
        int (**f)(int, int);
    } operators = {
        "+/*-",
        (char *[]) { "Addition", "Division", "Multiplication",  "Subtraction" },
        (int (*[])(int, int)) { addition, division, multiplication, subtraction }
    };
    for(;;) {
        symbol = prompt_char("Enter what do you want to do");
        char *offset = strchr(operators.symbol, symbol);
        if(offset) {
            op = offset - operators.symbol;
            break;
        }
        printf("Invalid operator\n");
    }
    printf(
        "%s: %d %c %d = %d\n",
        operators.name[op],
        a,
        symbol,
        b,
        operators.f[op](a, b)
    );
}
```

and here is an example run:

```
Enter first number
1
Enter second number
b
scanf failed
Enter second number
2
Enter what do you want to do
x
Invalid operator
Enter what do you want to do
*
Multiplication: 1 * 2 = 2
```

It's easy to add new operators, say, power:

```
int power(int a, int b) {
   if(b < 0) return 0;
   if(!b) return 1;
   while(b--) a *= a;
   return a;
}

//...
       
        "+/*^-",
        (char *[]) { "Addition", "Division", "Multiplication", "Power", "Subtraction" },
        (int (*[])(int, int)) { addition, division, multiplication, power, subtraction }
```